# Proof for Fourier transform in $L^2$

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

This question makes me really confused:

> Let $f$ and $g$ two functions in $L^2$. Show that: 
>   $$\int \widehat f\cdot gdx= \int f\cdot\widehat gdx,$$
>   where $\widehat f$ is the Fourier transform for the function $f$.

Notice that I need to prove it in $L^2$. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks,

Comment: Please write in Latex your question.

Comment: sorry, I`ll try to learn how to do that ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218537/multiplicative-formula-for-fourier-transforms), it's shown when $f$ and $g$ are $L^1$ functions. Then $f_n:=f\chi_{\{-n\leq f\leq n\}}$ and $g_n=g\chi_{\{-n\leq g\leq n\}}$ approximate respectively $f$ and $g$ in $L^2$, and are functions of $L^1$. So 
$$\int_{\Bbb R}f_n\widehat{g_n}dx=\int_{\Bbb R}\widehat{f_n}g_ndx.$$

Your task is to show that we can take the limit (use Plancherel's formula).

Comment: But here in the question we have that f and g are only L2 functions?

Comment: Yes, and since it's a homework question, I don't give the full answer. The idea is the following: it's not hard to do it when the functions are integrable. Now we try to jump to this case for functions in $L^2$ approximating them by integrable one.

Comment: you mean that I should first for example prove it for schwartz functions for example, then by density I can approximate any function in L2 by schwartz functions which will lead to the proof in L2?

Comment: Yes, that the idea.